# Passing commands to the Chrome terminal from other Chrome Apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I am thinking about a Caret and Secure Shell, all Chrome based developer workflow. I work on a remote server via ssh but develop locally. I use an dynamic language (R) so my current workflow involves writing some text in Sublime, highlighting what I want interpreted, and hitting “ctrl-enter” to send the text and execute it in a terminal widow which is ssh’d into the server. This way I can see results without an interruption in my R workflow. This is done with a script I edited from GitHub for Sublime and uses auto hot key. Is something similar possible using Caret (or any other Chrome text editor) and the Secure Shell app? Maybe it could be done with message passing instead of AHK?

Answer (score 0):

Both apps are open-source. You can build custom versions with as much integration as you'd like.

Inter-app communication in Chrome is done with [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external).

That said, I doubt that any such kind of interop is built into either of them.